# Serviço no workmanager roda somente no cabo usb pelo android studio

Tags: java, json, android-studio, api, android-service

Tenho uma aplicação android em que após o usuário inserir seu ID da empresa ele ativa um switch e a partir daí o aplicativo fica postando em uma API a posição dele. Isso é feito através do workmanager.

Segue minha classe do service

```java
public class TestWorker extends Worker {

    public TestWorker(
            @NonNull Context context,
            @NonNull WorkerParameters params) {
        super(context, params);
    }

    @Override
    public Result doWork() {

//        Log.d("DEBUG: ", "Serviço worker startando");
        String date = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss", Locale.getDefault()).format(new Date());
        String ra = getInputData().getString("ra");
//        Log.d("DEBUG", "ra que chega: "+ra);
        try {
            testPost(ra, date);
        } catch (ExecutionException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        // Indicate whether the task finished successfully with the Result
        return Result.success();
    }



    private void sendData(final String user_id, final String busca, final String data) {

        RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getApplicationContext());
        String url = "http://200.134.18.125:5000/api/v1/resources/positions/app";

        JSONObject js = new JSONObject();
        try {
            js.put("user_id", user_id);
            js.put("search", busca);
            js.put("date", data);
            Log.d("DEBUG json: ", "" + js);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST, url, js,
                new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
//                        Log.d("DEBUG: ", response.toString());
                    }
                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
//                Log.d("Error: ", "" + error.getMessage());
            }
        }) {
            @Override
            public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
                HashMap<String, String> headers = new HashMap<String, String>();
                headers.put("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8");
                return headers;
            }
        };
        queue.add(jsonObjectRequest);
    }

    private void testPost(String ra, String datetime) throws ExecutionException, InterruptedException {
        //String datetime = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss", Locale.getDefault()).format(new Date());
        //Log.d("DEBUG", "testando data: "+datetime);
        //String ra = "1111112";
        String search = "-100,-72,-74,-59,-79,-100"; //B8A
//        Log.d("DEBUG", "Busca: "+search+", ra: "+ra+", Data: "+datetime);
        sendData(ra,search, datetime);
    }
}
```

E aqui como eu inicio na MainActivity

```java
 @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        final Switch aSwitch = findViewById(R.id.switch1);
        final EditText editText = findViewById(R.id.ra);

        Constraints constraints = new Constraints.Builder()
                .setRequiresCharging(true)
                .build();


        aSwitch.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                if (isChecked) {
                    Log.d("DEBUG", "Começou..");
                    editText.setEnabled(false);

                    Data.Builder data = new Data.Builder();
                    data.putString("ra", editText.getText().toString());

                    PeriodicWorkRequest testWork = new PeriodicWorkRequest.Builder(TestWorker.class, 15, TimeUnit.MINUTES)
                            .addTag("APIPosting")
                            .setInputData(data.build())
                            .setConstraints(constraints)
                            .build();

                    WorkManager.getInstance(getApplicationContext())
                            .enqueue(testWork);

                    switchOnMsg();
                    Log.d("DEBUG", "Service Status: "+ (WorkManager.getInstance().getWorkInfoById(testWork.getId())));

                    //WorkManager.getInstance().cancelAllWorkByTag("APIPosting");

                    //Log.d("DEBUG", "Service Status apos cancelar: "+ (WorkManager.getInstance().getWorkInfoById(testWork.getId())));

                }else{
                    switchOffMsg();
                    editText.setEnabled(true);
                    //Log.d("DEBUG","Testwork: "+testWork);
                    WorkManager.getInstance().cancelAllWorkByTag("APIPosting");
                    //WorkManager.getInstance().cancelAllWork();

                    //Log.d("DEBUG", "Service Status: "+ (WorkManager.getInstance().getWorkInfoById(testWork.getId())));
                }
            }
        });
```

**Ao problema:**

Isso tudo funciona como eu quero. Posta a posição na API a cada 15 min normalmente. Porém se eu fizer sem o cabo USB conectado com a IDE ele para de funcionar. Reparei que o status do service fica como PENDING quando está sem o cabo, após ligar o cabo novamente no PC ele volta a fazer os posts na API.

Será que eu estou deixando passar algo obvio?

Meu manifest está dessa forma:

```
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"/>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:largeHeap="true"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <receiver android:name=".BootCompletedIntentReceiver">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

        <service android:name=".ScanService"></service>
        <service android:name=".TestService"/>

    </application>
```

O que eu preciso é saber como fazer com que o meu app faça os posts mesmo sem estar conectado ao cabo USB na IDE.

**Detalhes adicionais:**
*Como é um app de localização em que o usuário ativa ou não a localização do mesmo ele deve rodar em background a partir do momento que o switch for ativado mesmo que o celular bloqueie a tela*

Answer (score 0):

Resolvi o problema! 
O erro estava nesse trecho:

```java
  Constraints constraints = new Constraints.Builder()
                .setRequiresCharging(true)
                .build();
```

O método setRequiresCharging(true) que faz com que funcione somente quando está carregando.